# Controling colours in a scaterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, seaborn

Here is a mock DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
groups=pd.DataFrame({'Morph':np.random.choice(['S', 'Red'], 50),
                 'Tcross':np.random.rand(50)*0.2 ,  
                 'DeltaR12':np.random.rand(50)*2.0})
```

I plot a scatterplot this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams.update(pd.tools.plotting.mpl_stylesheet)
colors = pd.tools.plotting._get_standard_colors(len(groups), color_type='random')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_color_cycle(colors)
ax.margins(0.05)
for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group.DeltaR12, group.Tcross, marker='o',
            linestyle='', ms=5, label=name)
legend = ax.legend(numpoints=1, loc='upper left', shadow=True)

# Hereafter, code for the subsidiary question at the end or the post
# code doesn't produce anything
frame = legend.get_frame()
frame.set_facecolor('0.90')

for label in legend.get_lines():
    label.set_linewidth(1.5)  



ax.set_xlabel('$\Delta R_{12}$')
ax.set_ylabel('$T_{cross}$')
```

Resulting in

[image]

Or, alternatively, with seaborn's magic, in one line:

```
sns.swarmplot(x="DeltaR12", y="Tcross", data=groups, hue="MorphCen", size=6)
```

(which groups with my actual DataFrame without even have to drop ther other columns)

Resulting in

[image]

I would like to control the colours of categories: it looks dumb to have a label "Red" plotted in yellow or in blue! Moreover, spiral galaxies are blue, so plotting "S" categories in purple looks dumb to. How to control easily this colour choice?

Subsidiary, if someone knows how to draw a box around the legend, it would be nice, I don't understand the doc for automatic labels, only for manually set ones. :) I've tried something in the first code, as stated in comments, but it does not produce anything.

Thank you

Comment: Did you notice the `palette` keyword argument to [`swarmplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html)?

Comment: @Goyo  : I've tried the following code, but it does not produce what I want: `sns.swarmplot(x="DeltaR12", y="Tcross", data=Compact_SRed_Full_ML, hue="MorphCen", size=6,
              palette = sns.palplot(sns.xkcd_palette(["blue", "red"])))`

Comment: I wonder what you expect `sns.palplot` to return and why.

Comment: You could specify the colours you want in a list and introduce an index to access that colour in the `for` loop `ax.plot(group.DeltaR12, group.Tcross, marker='o',color = colour_lst[ind] ,linestyle='', ms=5, label=name)`

Comment: @sgDysregulation You're right, I've done something based on your suggestion. I didn't do it in a very beautiful way (I've set `ind=0` and then `ind+=1` in the loop...), but it works. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've figured out how to make that. First way, thanks to sgDysregulation (I have not implemented it in a very nice way, I'm sure there's better to do than this `ind` thing).

```
colour_lst=['r','b']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_color_cycle(colors)
ax.margins(0.05)
ind=0
for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group.DeltaR12, group.Tcross, marker='o',
            color = colour_lst[ind] ,linestyle='', ms=5, label=name)
    ind+=1  

ax.set_xlabel('$\Delta R_{12}$')
ax.set_ylabel('$T_{cross}$')
```

Second, more elegant:

```
def transcocol(morph):
    if (morph == 'S'):
        return'b'
    else:
        return'r'
MLtargetColour = MLtarget.apply (lambda x: transcocol (x))
pl.scatter(group.DeltaR12, group.Tcross, c=MLtargetColour);
```

And a last:

```
sns.swarmplot(x="DeltaR12", y="Tcross", 
              data=group, hue="MorphGal", palette="Set1",
              hue_order=['Red','S'], size=6)
```

Thank you very much.